# FireVault Password

Tags: password, touch-bar

I deleted some important files that run my MacBookPro(I am not specifically sure as I deleted thousands to open up space) Now the problem is my password works but every time it comes to ask for my password AGAIN to enable the touchID (mine is a 2017 MacBookPro with touch screen on it), the password never works. Then with Apple ID I reset my password again and again, the password never works when it comes to activating the TouchID. The problem is I want to log back in but the password never works( that's why I wonder some important key components are deleted). I am trying ti follow the instructions by reinstalling macOS Catalina and see if it works now.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! What files did you delete? What do you mean with "erase my mac"? Please clarify your question and wether you like to solve the TouchID password (that may have something to do with your Keychain password) or you want to solve the "Can't open device (69877) error. Thanks!

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz I am not able to log back in right now, and so Marc Wilson suggested reinstalling macOS, which is what I am doing right now. My goal is to try to log back in(after countless failures of getting my passwords right), and the least I want to do is erase the entire thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstall the OS.  This is a non-destructive process, and you have backups anyway, correct?

You can boot to Recovery mode and do this.  Refer to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314 for the details.